# Magento2 : How to show custom tables fields to system configuration drop down

Tags: magento2, collection, system-configuration

I am developing custom module, I want to display tables fields to system configuration drop down.

How to get all tables fields and set it to in drop down for system configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Just create system.xml file,***

**app/code/Packagename/SystemConfig/etc/adminhtml/system.xml,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="nis" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>NIS</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="nis" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Configuration</label>
            <tab>nis</tab>
            <resource>Packagename_SystemConfig::config_nis</resource>
            <group id="fields_list" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="table_field" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Table field</label>
                    <source_model>Packagename\SystemConfig\Model\Config\Source\Tablefield</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/Packagename/SystemConfig/Model/Config/Source/Tablefield.php**

```
<?php
namespace Packagename\SystemConfig\Model\Config\Source;

class Tablefield implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve option values array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = ['label' => __('Table Field'), 'value' => 'tablefield'];
        foreach ($this->getTablefield() as $field) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $field['COLUMN_NAME'], 'value' => $field['COLUMN_NAME']];
        }
        return $options;
    }
    public function getTablefield(){
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $customTable = $connection->getTableName('sales_order');
        /* you can change your magento dabase name below */
        $allField = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'magento2' AND TABLE_NAME = '".$customTable."'"); //magento2 is database name
        return $allField;
    }


}
```